# Async methods does not work properly in initState

Tags: flutter

I am executing those two functions in the initState (in this order):

```
  getUsers() async {
    usersStream = authBloc.getUsers();
    usersStream.listen((allUsers) {
      for (ApplicationUser user in allUsers) {
        users.add(user.username);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
  fetchEvent() async {
    await eventBloc.getEvent(widget.eventId).then((value) {
      event = value;
      title.text = event.title;
      for (var j = 0; j < event.dienstMap["Besetzung"].length; j++) {
        besetzungsList.add(event.dienstMap["Besetzung"][j]);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < event.dienstMap["Aufgabe"].length; i++) {
        aufgabenList.add(event.dienstMap["Aufgabe"][i]);
        zeitList.add(event.dienstMap["Aufgabe"][i]);
        teamList.add(event.dienstMap["Team"][i]);

        dataTableRows.add(DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text(event.dienstMap["Aufgabe"][i]),
              onTap: () {
                removeRow(i);
              },
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text(event.dienstMap["Zeit"][i]),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text(event.dienstMap["Team"][i]),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            DataCell((i > event.dienstMap["Besetzung"].length - 1 == true)
                ? DropDown(
                    hint: "Wählen",
                    users: users,
                    besetzungsListChanged: (String value) {
                      besetzungsList.removeAt(i);
                      besetzungsList.insert(i, value);
                    },
                    fromDropDown: (bool value) => fromDropDown = value,
                  )
                : DropDown(
                    hint: event.dienstMap["Besetzung"][i],
                    users: users,
                    besetzungsListChanged: (String value) {
                      besetzungsList.removeAt(i);
                      besetzungsList.insert(i, value);
                      //besetzungsList.replaceRange(start, end, replacement)
                    },
                    fromDropDown: (bool value) => fromDropDown = value,
                  ))
          ],
        ));
      }
    });
  }
```

In the `fetchEvent` method I am using the `users` list, to which I am adding values in `getUsers` method.

The problem is, that the values of the list are not there, when the `fetchEvent` method gets executed. After hot reload the values are there and I can use the dropdown button.

Comment: you need to call them like: `getUsers().then((_) => fetchEvent())`

Comment: Your `getUsers` function doesn't seem to do any asynchronous work (or if it does, it doesn't wait for any asynchronous work to complete, nor does it return a `Future` to its caller to indicate when it completes).